# Are creatures with magic immunity affected by sanctuary?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

As last week's game ended in a tough spot, I need rules advice to make critical tactical decisions, since I'm new to pathfinder and we are playing a pretty hard campaing.

Our lvl 3-4 party of 5 is facing a small and nerfed version of a [stone golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-stone), and I think our only chance is to run at this point. I plan to make a last stand with [Sanctuary](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/sanctuary.html#sanctuary) to at least allow my team to survive. However, the golem is inmune to magic.

**RAW, would a *Stone Golem*'s *Immunity to Magic* make him not affected by *Sanctuary*, or would it need to make a Will save as any other creature?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, it is affected.** Although the [immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Immunity-Ex-or-Su-) rule is somewhat open-ended, the general idea is that a creature cannot be harmed by or gain conditions from whatever they are immune to. The [stone golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-stone)'s ability is special:

> Immunity to Magic (Ex) A stone golem is immune to any spell or spell-like ability that allows spell resistance. In addition, certain spells and effects function differently against the creature, as noted below.

It then lists some damage and debuff spells that have secondary effects.

Luckily for you, Sanctuary does not allow spell resistance, and does not impose a specific condition or harm an attacking creature. Additionally, none of the golem's [construct traits](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/universalMonsterRules.html#construct-traits) apply to the effects of Sanctuary, and so it would still need to pass the Will save to hit you. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a reason you listed the CLAY golem's Immunity? I mean, it's identical except for the critter name, but...why not use the one you're actually referring to?

Comment: So as long as the spell doesn't allow Spell Resistance, the golem will be affected by it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, unless otherwise noted

The [Immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Immunity-Ex-or-Su-) ability makes you immune to all damage and secondary effects based on the source of your immunity. So a creature immune to fire would be immune to fire damage and all secondary effects from a fire source. A [fire elemental](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-fire/medium-fire-elemental/) is immune both to *any* fire damage and effects like the *Fireworks* effect of [Pyrotecnics](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pyrotechnics/).

### However, a stone golem is not immune to sanctuary

The [Stone Golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-stone) immunity is more specific, and doesn't work on all forms of magic:

> **Immunity to Magic (Ex)**
>   A stone golem is immune to any spell or spell-like ability **that allows spell resistance**. In addition, certain spells and effects function differently against the creature, as noted below.

In other words, if the spell or spell-like ability allows [spell resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Resistance), the golem is immune to it. But spells and spell-like abilities that do not allow spell resistance, like [Acid Splash](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-splash/), [Create Pit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-pit/) or [Sanctuary](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sanctuary/), will work against the stone golem normally.

> Spell Resistance **no**

Also, Sanctuary is a spell of the [Abjuration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Abjuration) school, and not tagged by any of the mental-affecting effects that constructs are generally immune to:

> Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms).

Neither it is of any of the physically-affecting effects that they are also immune to:

> Immunity to bleed, disease, death effects, necromancy effects, paralysis, poison, sleep effects, and stunning.

So, if you had immunity to *Abjuration* effects, or immunity to *divine spells*, or even immunity to *effects that require a will save*, all would apply against *Sanctuary*. But that's not the case for stone golems.